# Which site is best to store images anonymously using api?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to store images on some third party website so i can use the same on my website.
I want to know is there any website available on which I can store my images anonymously, without
any authentication from the user.
Is there any website which provides API for the same.
help me.

Comment: I think you should review the page about what to ask here. I am undecided between off-topic for opinion based or off-topic for request to find tools or resources.

Comment: why downvoted? i asked genuine question, i was facing difficulty in finding solution for this issue.?

Answer (score 3):

Well you can use imgur API, it allows you to store images on site anonymously.
find the details on the following link.

https://api.imgur.com/endpoints

hope this will help you.

Comment: Imgur's ToS says *don't use Imgur as a content delivery network* which seems to be at odds with OP wanting to upload arbitrary images to use on his site. *I want to store images on some third party website so i can use the same on my website*